# Complex Exponential in Differential Equations.

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I am a physics student, but have taken courses in analysis and algebra.

My knowledge of differential equations is purely methodical, and I was hoping for a more math oriented insight with regards to making use of the complex exponential when solving ODEs (for example, the damped oscillator with a sinusoidal driving force). What is it about the field $\mathbb{C}$ and the complex exponential that we are making use of when we convert our differential equation? Is it merely the 'easy' derivative? Is there an algebraic way to understand it?

Comment: Consider the equation $$e^{f(x)}=f'(x)e^{f(x)}$$ which gives the solution of equation $$ \dot{x}=\alpha(t)x.$$ This idea works with complex exponential too.

Comment: I am confused by your question. Are you trying to ask why we use complex functions in odes or specifically for forced equations?

Comment: I would like a "deep" reason why we use complex functions in ODEs.

Comment: I think the biggest reason as to why exponentials pop up is because the exponential function is the unique fuction that has its derivative equal to itself

Comment: And because $\sin x=\frac1{2i}(e^{ix}-e^{-ix})=Im(e^{ix})$ and single exponentials on the right side are slightly easier to handle than the their compositions to sin and cos. If the right side is a sum of term, you can compose the particular solution by summing up one solution for each term.

Comment: Tried to clarify my question a bit more.